# Stop dropdown behavior when specific menu - Foundation 6

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, zurb-foundation, responsive

I use Foundation 6 and the responsive menu to change appereance menus like this :

```
<ul class='wrapper-list' data-responsive-menu='large-dropdown' data-disable-hover='true' data-autoclose='false' data-click-open='true'>
```

When screen is **large** I have a dropdown but when I resize screen to small/ medium menu stay in dropdown and this is a big problem for me.

If I load my page in small size my list is visible and I don't have dropdown, but if switch with large screen and small again menu disappear like dropdown behavior...

How can I "reset" menu with initial appearance (html basic) with no interaction of js when screen is small ?

Do you know if there is a rule to say **large-dropdown-only** like visibility class ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for this horrible english...

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or your entire menu code please?

Comment: It's difficult, there is a lot of lines my problem is "simple" I use foundation's dropdown like this : `<ul class='wrapper-list' data-responsive-menu='large-dropdown' data-disable-hover='true' data-autoclose='false' data-click-open='true'>` despite of data-responsive on large, dropdown works on small

Answer (score 0):

Foundation is mobile first, so you need to set dropdown class for small screen. It works similar to column's clases. If you set class only for small, all screens will inherit.

Prefixes **medium** and **large** are required.

Prefix **small** is not required, so any menu specific class without prefix will be considered as class for small.

If you have two classes without prefix, the last one of that two will be used for small screen.

Also if you have two classes with same prefix, the last one of that two will be used for that screen size.

```
<ul class"dropdown medium-accordion large-drilldown menu"></ul>
```